# How to create batch script to keep rerunning command

Tags: windows, script, cmd.exe

I just downloaded Win 10 and I'm having activation issues. I hear if I keep rerunning this - "slmgr.vbs /ato" command it will eventually activate.

Can someone give me a quick little script to have this keep rerunning this command forever until I end it? Possibly wait 5 seconds after each time it runs. After the command runs a little box comes up (that tells you if windows activated correctly) which you need to hit OK on before the script can be run again. Not sure if this can automatically be OKd with the script you write.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? if slmgr.vbs /ato doesn't work, then it will never work (no matter how many times you run it) until you fix the original activation issue.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Windows has not been activated". This is because the activation servers are clogged today. I've heard that if I keep rerunning this command and spamming the activation servers it will eventually activate. I figure it's easier to run a script then to manually keep trying to activate myself.

Comment: In general Windows will automatically try to activate itself every x amount of time (can't remember the exact time period). So in general the issue will probably sort itself out automatically over the next few days and no need for a script

Comment: That's true. I was able to actually get it to activate myself just now after rerunning that command a bunch. This thread can be closed.

Comment: I just pasted my comment above as an answer, you can accept the answer to close it.

Answer (score 0):

In general Windows will automatically try to activate itself every x amount of time (can't remember the exact time period). So in general the issue will probably sort itself out automatically over the next few days and no need for a script